# Moving data from oine Elasticsearch index to another with higher number of shards or increasing shard number in existing index

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and I have been reading documentation in order to find a way of increasing amount of shards that my index consists of. Currently my index looks like this:

```
country_data                              0     p      STARTED     227 100.7kb 192.168.0.115 $HOSTNAME
country_data                              0     r      STARTED     227 100.7kb 192.168.0.116 $HOSTNAME
```

I wanted to increase the number of shard to 5 however I was unable to find a proper way of doing it. I learnt from another Stackoverflow question that I should be able to do it like this:

```
POST _reindex?slices=5
{
  "source": {
    "index": "country_data"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "country_data_new"
  }
}
```

However when I did that I got a copy of my country_data with same amount of shards and replicas (1 and 1). I tried to learn more about it in documentation but all I found is this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/option_slices.html

I couldn't find anything in documentation about increasing number of shards in existing index or how can I move data to new index which would have more shards. I would be grateful for any insights into this problem or at least a website where could I learn how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

###### This can be done in any of the below mentioned way.

**1st Option** : You can use the elastic search **[Split Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-split-index.html)**.
I suggest you to please go through the **[documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-split-index.html)** once before proceeding with this method.

**2nd Option** : [Create a new index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) with same mappings and give the required settings for new shards. Then use the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) to copy data from source index to destination index

To create the new Index:

```
PUT /<NEW_INDEX_NAME>
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": <REQUIRED_NUMBER_OF_SHARDS>
    },
    "mappings": {<MAPPINGS_OF_SOURCE_INDEX>}
  }
}
```

If you don't give the number of shards in the settings while creating an index, by default it creates index with one primary and one replica shard.

To Reindex from source to newly created index:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "<SOURCE_INDEX_NAME>"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "<NEW_INDEX_NAME>"
  }
}
```